# Cannot stack two ggplotly plot using Rmd file in Rshiny report

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, r-plotly

I built an RSiny app which can download a html report using downloadHandler. However, in Rmd file, I can not stack two ggplotly side by side although I tried many options. You can see my code in Rmd file below. After this code, I still get two ggplotly plow vertical. It does not work. Could you please help? Thank you

Rmd file:

```
{r echo=FALSE, out.width="49%", fig.width=3, fig.height=3,fig.show='hold',fig.align='center'}

ggplotly(qplot( params$sdr_v$Voltage_sensor, params$sdr_v$sdr, xlab= "Voltage sensors", ylab = "SDR(mV/day)")+
geom_point(aes(x = params$sdr_v$Voltage_sensor, y= params$sdr_v$sdr))+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1.0, hjust = 1.0))+
theme(legend.position = "none",axis.text.x=element_blank()))

ggplotly(qplot( params$sdr_s$Voltage_sensor, params$sdr_s$sdr_soc, xlab= "Voltage sensors", ylab = "SDR (%SOC/day)")+
geom_point(aes(x = params$sdr_s$Voltage_sensor, y= params$sdr_s$sdr_soc, colour=params$sdr_s$sdr_soc>0.016))+
scale_colour_manual(values = c("black", "red"))+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1.0, hjust = 1.0))+
theme(legend.position = "none",axis.text.x=element_blank()))
```

Answer (score 1):

The **plotly** graphics are "HTML widgets", so you can use `combineWidgets` from the **manipulateWidget** package.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(plotly)
library(manipulateWidget)
```

```{r}
gg1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()
gg2 <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) + geom_point(alpha = 0.2)
ggly1 <- ggplotly(gg1)
ggly2 <- ggplotly(gg2)
combineWidgets(ggly1, ggly2, nrow = 1)
```
````

[image]

Set the chunk option `out.width = "100%"` if you want to use the full width of the page:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this answer solved my issue!